# In Adrian Tchaikovsky's "Children of Ruin," what is the ship the Voyager encounters as it enters the Nod system?

Tags: children-of-time-series

I may have missed it. The *Voyager* encounters a destroyed ship leaving the system. It is implied that it is a dead ship, possibly destroyed in the ongoing conflict. But why was it racing out of the system and why was it dead?

Comment: Are you talking about the 27km diameter mostly-spherical ship that was full of water before it burst and leaked out?  The one that *Voyager* meets in chapter "Present 1"?

Comment: Yes that's the one

Comment: Looks like they decided to skip investigation of that ship?

Comment: Yeah it seems that way. I was hoping the octopuses would mention it or something and I just missed it